# placing Backbone.js templates into separate HTML files

Tags: templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I just took over a web application from another developer, and I'm trying to clean it up.  Currently there is only a single HTML file, and it is over 1,000 lines long.  It contains at least a dozen Backbone templates, and I would really like to separate them into their own files.  I'm not an expert in Backbone, and I've been searching the internet for a good while without finding much help.  It seems that there should be a very simple, elegant, and even recommended way of doing this, but I have yet to discover it.

So, say we've got some code like this in index.html:

```
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate1">
    <p>Hello</p>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate2">
    <p>World!</p>
</script>
```

How can I place them in separate files, such that Backbone will still be able to access them?

Edit:
Hi Anatoliy, thank you for your help.  I've had some time to play around with this today, but I'm not sure where to put things.  I inherited this code:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
        jqueryUI = require('jquery-ui');

    var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'myView',
        template: Handlebars.compile($('#myView').html()),
```

So where would you recommend putting the code you suggested?  I tried inserting it in the Handlebars.compile() function with no luck.  Thank you for your help, I just can't seem to find much of anything on the internet in terms of examples or guides.

Answer (score 1):

Use require-js. Specifically with `require-handlebars` plugin (or whichever templating engine you prefer)

https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin

That way you get to put your templates into separate files, then load them in by doing:

```
define(['hbs!your/template/file'], function(tpl){
    var html = tpl({data: 'stuff'});
});
```

Comment: Hi Anatoliy, thank you for your response!  But I'm still a bit confused.  Do I have to use Node for this plugin?  This project doesn't use Node, and I'm completely ignorant of how Node works :)

It seems to me that Backbone should have a way to do this, without adding other libraries.  I've heard great things about Backbone, and I'll be quite underwhelmed if it cannot handle something so essential.

Comment: nope you just use require.js which dynamically loads JS (and with the help of require-handlebars Handlebars templates as well) http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach mentioned by *require-handlebars-plugin* but when trying to precompile them to use in production.  using *require-handlebars-plugin* wasn't straight forward I managed to do this but after I spent much time debugging this, , my advice is to precompile templates from the beginning because changing this before production wasn't hasslefree.

You can use approach like:
http://nuunoo.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/javascript-pre-compiled-templates-with-handlebars-js/
and use grunt task for automating this:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars

Comment: Hi HO_BA, thanks for your response!  Unfortunately, I don't have experience with grunt.  Is it difficult to set up?

Comment: No, actually it automates the development process you can start with https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/meet-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript--net-24856 or you can try [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which is totally great and makes it easy to use grunt and other powerful tools like bower. Best of luck